# Bet on Sharepoint 2010 Workflows?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow-foundation

I am looking into Sharepoint 2010 currently and it seems to me the workflow engine being used is based on WWF 3.5. I wonder if it's a good idea to do this as WWF has been gone through dramatic changes with version 4. I wonder if the investments would be save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WF in .NET 3.X and WF in .NET 4 are both powerful workflow platforms.  The workflow platform in SharePoint 2007 was based on .NET 3.0 and hence bringing forth that support into SharePoint 2010 brings a proven workflow engine to excute SharePoint hosted workflows.

The timing of the release of .NET 4 simply didn't allow for it to be baked into SharePoint 2010.

Comment: not really a direct answer to my question but I get it. Architecture it the stuff that is hard to change and I am afraid that Sharepoint 2010 suggests .NET4 as does VS2010 and you end up investing in WWF3 which has been changed a lot in .NET4. But at the end of the day it is an individual decision. Thanx for all the contributions.

Answer (score 0):

From [Improvements in SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335710.aspx) dated Nov 2009:

> It should be noted that SharePoint
>   2010 requires .NET Framework 3.5. The
>   next version of the .NET Framework 4.0
>   is currently in development but
>   product timelines meant SharePoint
>   2010 was not dependent on it.

Hence the workflows in SPS2010 are built on top of Windows Workflows for .NET 3.5 and not .NET 4.0.

Comment: I knew SP 2010 is based on .NET 3.5 but woud you bet on the Workflow part?

Comment: I remember reading it somewhere while working on SPS2010 a while back, let me find it and update this.

Comment: Well, couldn't find the exact link but this diagram at the official SPS2010 documentation site @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557253(v=office.14).aspx pretty much sums it up.